# mongodb version 2.4.9, cannot start mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation, nosql

I have to install mongodb version 2.4.9 according to project requirement. But I can't start the mongodb service after installing. The error is as follow.

```
systemctl status mongodb.service
● mongodb.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongodb; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ဟူး 2018-03-28 22:04:36 +0630; 28s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 31482 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongodb start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: utility, e.g. service mongodb start
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongodb
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu mongodb[31482]: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start mongodb.service.
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
မတ် 28 22:04:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please..

Comment: More info needed. What your mongodb.log file says? `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` (or similar.. Check /etc/mongod.conf)

Comment: There is no log under `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`. It  just keep failing failed when I start `sudo service mongodb start`

Comment: It means that mongod -user don't own all needed resources. What are all paths listed at your mongod.conf file? All those must be owned by mongod user. (pid -file path, data directory, log-file directory)

Comment: `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`
`logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`
how do I set to be owned by mongo user

Comment: `sudo chown -R mongod: /var/lib/mongodb` and `sudo chown -R mongod: /var/log/mongodb`

Comment: It is showing `chown: invalid spec: ‘mongod:’`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167752/discussion-between-jjussi-and-aung-ko-ko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sudo -u mongodb /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf` starts mongod as it should be, there must be something wrong at `/etc/init.d/monngodb` -script...